# Pivot tables from a table that has Month headers & Sales value as value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Ok so I have a table that looks like the following.

I want to be able to create a pivot table from it so that I can get sales value filtered by month from each customer.

[image]

I think i need to have a table that repeats customer name 12 times (once for each month) for a pivot to work.

Please help 
I'd really appreciate it.

Best

Comment: you need to `un-pivot` your data first look into how to do this with power pivot

Comment: Did you try to use Power Query?